# Expo wont start new project

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to start fresh new project. I use expo init name to create new project. Than i navigate to folder and run npm start and it always run old project. What I am doing wrong. I tryed restarting everything and creating new project few times but it always start same old project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by removing all data and cache from Expo mobile app.